# como modifico la información que viene desde un endpoint en angular

Tags: angular, pipe

la problemática es la siguiente en angular tengo ciertos datos que me envían desde un endpoint el cual es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la información que trae lo muestro de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta aquí todo bien lo que necesito es lo siguiente necesito cambiar esos datos para que sea mas entendible para el cliente de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el servicio para consumir la información del endpoind

```
    export class DashboardService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private AuthService: AuthService) {}
  //dashboard

  getDashboard = (): Promise<any> => {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(environment.host + 'dashboard', {
        headers: this.AuthService.userHeadersJSON(),
      })
      .toPromise();
  };
}
```

el component.ts en esta parte existe una grafica pero no le tomen inportancia lo que importa es donde se muestran los datos de "productos mas vendidos","top aseguradoras"

```
  constructor(private DashboardService: DashboardService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.DashboardService.getDashboard().then(
      ({
        incomePerMonth,
        salesPerMonth,
        topInsurances,
        topProduct,
        topVehicles,
        totalIncome,
        totalSales,
      }: any) => {
        let objectIncomePerMonth = { data: [], label: 'Ingresos por mes' };

        incomePerMonth.forEach((element) => {
          objectIncomePerMonth.data.push(element.total);

          this.barChartLabelsIncomePerMonth.push(
            this.DiccionarioMeses.filter((e) => e.id === element.month)[0].label
          );
        });

        this.barChartDataIncomePerMonth.push(objectIncomePerMonth);

        let objectSalesPerMonth = { data: [], label: 'Ventas por mes' };

        salesPerMonth.forEach((element) => {
          objectSalesPerMonth.data.push(element.total);

          this.barChartLabelsSalesPerMonth.push(
            this.DiccionarioMeses.filter((e) => e.id === element.month)[0].label
          );
        });

        this.barChartDataSalesPerMonth.push(objectSalesPerMonth);

        this.topProduct = topProduct;

        this.topInsurances = topInsurances;

        this.topVehicles = topVehicles;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

y el component.html que es donde pinto los datos que se muestran

```
<diV class="row" style="margin-top: 10px; margin:20px; ">
  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margins6">
    <h3 style="margin-left: 15px">Productos más vistos</h3>
    <ol>
      <li *ngFor="let producto of topProduct">
        {{ producto.product }} {{ producto.provider }}
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margins6">
    <h3 style="margin-left: 15px">Top aseguradoras</h3>
    <ol>
      <li *ngFor="let insurances of topInsurances">{{ insurances | uppercase}}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margins6">
    <h3 style="margin-left: 15px">Top de vehiculos asegurados</h3>
    <ol>
      <li *ngFor="let vehicles of topVehicles">
        {{ vehicles.brand }} {{ vehicles.model }} {{ vehicles.year }}
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</diV>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La opción mas rápida que pudiera implementar con esos datos que recibes es un pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'productoProvider'
})
export class ProductoProviderPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): string {

    switch (value) {
      case 'AM':
        return 'Amplia'
      case 'ES':
        return 'Esencial';
      case 'Basico':
        return 'Básico';
      case 'Pro':
        return 'Pro'
      default:
        return '';

    }
  }
}
```

Luego en tu html aplicas el pipe personalizado

```
 <ol>
      <li *ngFor="let producto of topProduct">
        {{ producto.product }} {{ producto.provider | productoProvider}}
      </li>
 </ol>
```